# Pandas: value_counts and cut with groupby multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

With a DataFrame like this:

```
time    location
1       A
1       A
2       B
4       A
9       A
12      B
12      B
12      B
18      A
```

I can get a count of the number of occurrences within a time bin by doing the following cut and value_counts operations:

```
d = {'time': [1,1,2,4,9,12,12,12,18], 'location': ['A','A','B','A','A','B','B','B','A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
time_bins = np.arange(0, 100, 10)
cut_frame = pd.cut(df.time, bins=time_bins)
counts = pd.value_counts(cut_frame,sort=False)
count_frame = pd.DataFrame(counts)
count_frame.index.name = 'time_window'
```

The resulting DataFrame looks like this:

```
time_window time
(0, 10]     5
(10, 20]    4
```

How can I break this down further by the `location` series to get something like this with a MultiIndex?

```
location  time_window
A    (0, 10]    4
     (10, 20]   1
B    (0, 10]    1
     (10, 20]   3
```

Or this?

```
time_window     location    time
(0, 10]         A           4
(0, 10]         B           1
(10, 20]        A           1
(10, 20]        B           3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append your `cut_frame` to your original `df` and then apply `groupby`:

```
df["time_window"] = cut_frame
df.groupby(["location", "time_window"]).count().dropna()
```